# Having error on the READ statement: Error 90 File access and properties are incompatible

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am getting the error message:

> Error 90 File access and properties are incompatible

The piece of code that gives me the error is the following:

```
  PARAMETER (NPT=250, NPR=9)
  IMPLICIT  REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
  CHARACTER*255 ARQDAT
  DIMENSION Z(NPT,NPT,NPR) 
  COMMON/CPROP/ TMIN,TMAX,DT,PMIN,PMAX,DP,VMIN,VMAX,DX,DX2,DY,DY2,Z
  REAL*4 RGAS        
!*     Read matrix
  OPEN(UNIT=10,FILE=ARQDAT,FORM='UNFORMATTED', ACCESS='DIRECT',RECL=1)
  READ(10) Z !this is the statement giving error ARQDAT is a binary file
  CLOSE(UNIT=10)
```

Why or what should I do?

Comment: Change the record length to 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You opened the file ACCESS='DIRECT' but are doing a sequential READ on it - this is not allowed. Often when people do ACCESS='DIRECT',RECL='1' they want to read a byte at a time, but you have to combine this with a REC= value in the READ statement. In modern Fortran there are other, better ways to do this (such as ACCESS='STREAM').

What compiler are you using and on what operating system?

Comment: Wow, Steve Lionel himself is now on SO!

Comment: Hi I am using Silverfrost Plato IDE. So it does not accept access=stream. only direct, sequential, transparent and append are acceptable. Also I tried sequential access and the error I get is that it is trying to read beyond the end of the file. Sorry for such amateur questions, I am more of a user than a programmer. THe old Fortran77 program had only OPEN(UNIT=10,FILE=ARQDAT,FORM='BINARY') written on it. As I have to make changes in the source code I am encountering these problems. Any tips?

Comment: I also tried compiling with MS visual studio 2010 and intel visual fortran composer XE 2013. The MSVS compiler gives me the following error when I try to debug: The program '[22360] SCROLLV2.exe: Native' has exited with code 24 (0x18)

Comment: Well, that means that the program got an "End of file during read" error. What exactly do you want to be in variable Z? What wrote the file and how big is the file (in exact number of bytes if you can)? What does the READ statement look like now?  You could use FORM="BINARY" with Intel Visual Fortran (or replace that with FORM="UNFORMATTED",ACCESS="STREAM") Do you have 250x250x250 double precision reals in the data file?

Comment: I can bypass that problem now with the form=binary in intel visual fortran. thank you.